# Invalid Bundle Structure The binary file is not permitted in xCode 11 when uploaded on app store

Tags: ios, app-store, xcode11

**Error**

I'm getting below error when trying to upload my IPA on AppStore.

> ERROR ITMS-90171: "Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file is not permitted. Your app can’t contain standalone executables or libraries, other than the CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles. Refer to the Bundle Programming Guide at https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=bundle-structure for information on the iOS app bundle structure."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I was working in Xcode 11.2. So I am unable to solve this issue. But when I run the code on Xcode 11.4.1 then it is working fine. The app is uploaded on the app store first time on XCode 11.4.1. Thanks.

Comment: I am using Xcode 12.2 and facing the same issue